# Alter Table Difference?

Tags: sql, alter

Is there a difference between

## 1st Way

```
Alter Table Test_Table 
Add Test_Column
```

and

## 2nd way

```
Alter Table Test_Table 
Add Column Test_Column
```

Comment: Same result. Just a matter of taste.

Comment: @Meer_Deen both are not same in MS SQL

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Alter Table Test_Table Add Test_Column
   Use for Add new columns in table
2. Alter Table Test_Table Add Column Test_Column 
   use for Modify column in table

Comment: no you can not modify column without "Column " keyword in MS SQL

Comment: Who said modify? And who said MS SQL Server?

Comment: @ jarlh it's SQl Server Syntex for add / modify not mine

Comment: I understand that. But as you can see SQL Server has not been tagged here. And the question seems to be about adding a column.

Comment: @ jarlh   @Christian asking difference between two statement so i try to explain

Comment: alter table test alter  id varchar(100) NULL  : is Not working in SQL

Comment: alter table test alter column id varchar(100) NULL it's working fine

Comment: @ jarlh  you good reputation why you asking such type comment without understand question..

Comment: You're still talking about MS SQL Server, not ANSI SQL... (Which is presumed of no dbms is specified in question.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the database.

For example Oracle enough

```
ALTER TABLE xxx ADD column_name TYPE;
```

But in postgresql you must `column` after `add`

```
ALTER TABLE xxx ADD COLUMN column_name TYPE;
```

Comment: And ANSI SQL has the `COLUMN` keyword as optional, i.e. both versions are allowed.

Comment: @Abihabi87  nice same thing i have  try to   expalnin @ jarlh  COLUMN  alter modify column not working in SQL Server 2012